# F# floor function doesn't round properly?

Tags: math, f#, floor

I have a super strange issue. Here's my simple piece of recursive code:

```
let float2cfrac x =
    let rec tofloat (lst : int list) (xi : float) =

        let qi = floor xi
        let ri = xi-qi

        printfn "%A %A %A %A" xi qi ri (1.0/ri)
        if ri > (floor 0.0) then          
            tofloat (lst @ [int qi]) (1.0/ri)
        else
            lst
    tofloat [] x
```

I'm not going to explain my code much, as the issue i'm having seems quite basic.
The printfn will print xi and qi, where qi is simply the floor of xi.
When looking at the output, it looks like once the software reaches a round number for xi, the floor function removes 1, instead of doing nothing.

Here's my output for the number 3.245, which should complete computing after just a few calculations:

float2cfrac 3.245;;

3.245 3.0 0.245 4.081632653

4.081632653 4.0 0.08163265306 12.25

12.25 12.0 0.25 4.0

4.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 - Here it gets messed up. Floor of 4.0 should be 4, right?

1.0 1.0 4.035882739e-12 2.477772682e+11

2.477772682e+11 2.477772682e+11 0.2112731934 4.733208147

4.733208147 4.0 0.7332081468 1.363869188

If anybody has an explanation for this or some sugguestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `decimal` over `float`. `decimal` is floating point like `float` but it is base10 rather than base2 as well as being 96 bit. This gives you greater precision and you don't get rounding issues from that numbers like `3.245` isn't exactly representable in base2.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Unfortunately without any change of result at all.

Answer (score 7):

A super well known issue: floating-point numbers have finite precision, so you can't generally count on the same calculation done via different methods to produce the same result. There will always be a margin of error.

The corollary is that you can't compare floating-point numbers for strict equality. You have to take their difference and compare it to some very small number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean something like if ri > 0.00000 then?
Or am I misunderstanding your explanation completely?

Comment: `0.00000` is the same as just `0`. You should do `ri >= 0.00001`.

Comment: Wow, that worked. But i'm not sure I understand it completely.
How do I know that ri doesn't become less than 0.00001, wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: Actually the result is wrong. The issue is still, that 4.0 gets rounded down to 3.0

Comment: Have you tried comparing `abs(ri) >= Double.Epsilon` or whatever your desired precision is. Also, see [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10143/Floating-Point-in-NET-part-Concepts-and-Formats).

Comment: See also http://floating-point-gui.de/. What's going on when see 4.0 being rounded down to 3.0 is that that "4.0" value has actually been calculated as 3.9999999 or so, due to accumulated rounding error in the previous steps of your calculation. The `printfn` code includes code that rounds 3.9999999 up to 4.0 visually since that's what people expect to see, but `floor` treats it as being really 3.9999999 so it rounds, correctly, down to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the numerical issues of floats by not using floats. Here one solution is to represent the input as a rational number, i.e integer numerator and integer denominator, and then adjust the formulas accordingly.

```
open System.Numerics

let number2cfrac (xNumerator : int) (xDenominator : int) =
    let rec loop acc (xin : BigInteger) (xid : BigInteger) =
        let qi = xin / xid
        let rin = xin - (qi * xid)
        printfn "%A %A %A %A" (float xin / float xid) qi (float rin / float xid) (float xid / float rin)
        if rin <> BigInteger.Zero then        
            loop (int qi :: acc) xid rin
        else
            List.rev acc
    loop [] (BigInteger(xNumerator)) (BigInteger(xDenominator))

> number2cfrac 3245 1000;;
3.245 3 0.245 4.081632653
4.081632653 4 0.08163265306 12.25
12.25 12 0.25 4.0
4.0 4 0.0 infinity
val it : int list = [3; 4; 12]
```